# Why lib3ds can't open this max model?

Tags: 3dsmax

I'm using [lib3ds](http://code.google.com/p/lib3ds/)'s 3dsplay example to load [this model](http://down.3dmodelfree.com:9696/1106/model/2012/08/asdb062362.rar), whose suffix is `.max`

but get this error:

```
3dsplayer: Error: Loading 3DS file failed.
```

But it can load the `.3ds` model shipped with lib3ds.

Why lib3ds can't open this `.max` model?

Answer (score 1):

.3ds format is (fairly) standard format used by very, very old 3d studio. It's supported by many modelling packages as one export format.

3ds max's format is different. 3ds max is actually a framework with lots and lots of plugins, and each of these store their data in different ways, and thus the .max format isn't very well defined (I doubt anyone has even tried).

In short: lib3ds won't load .max files, because they are not .3ds files.

Comment: Can you recommend a lib that can load .max files?

Comment: Like I said, I doubt one exists. Load the model in max and export in some other format.